# Grub2 ignore my grub.cfg

Tags: grub2

My `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is the following, but I can't have the countdown or the auto select after 10 seconds:

```
#
#
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="menu"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX="keep"


### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom_proxy ###
menuentry "Linux Mint 20.1 Cinnamon" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-81c9ce81-1dd0-4887-b480-d80356c3c26e' {
    #recordfail
    #load_video
    #gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod all_video
    insmod gzio
    insmod xzio
    insmod lzopio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='hd0,msdos1'  81c9ce81-1dd0-4887-b480-d80356c3c26e
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 81c9ce81-1dd0-4887-b480-d80356c3c26e
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-58-generic root=UUID=81c9ce81-1dd0-4887-b480-d80356c3c26e ro    $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-58-generic
}
menuentry "Windows"{
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    insmod fat
    set root='hd4,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd4,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd4,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci4,gpt1  5EAE-5C3F
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5EAE-5C3F
        fi
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

**How I solved, but I can't understand it**

I added this 2 files into the /etc/grub.d/ directory:

**00_header** : https://gist.github.com/angerangel/aba4d3fcf57478218a09904876ea6c37

**10_linux**: https://gist.github.com/angerangel/04419010f15fd6a5e1b0dc94b2899231

but these files are too complex, I can't understand why the simply file was ignore  and this last resulting file works. (Grub 1 was so simply)

Comment: Is Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode from MBR(msdos) drive and Windows in UEFI boot mode from gpt. Best not to mix boot modes, and can only do that if separate drives. And then can only dual boot from UEFI boot menu. UEFI & BIOS are not compatible, once you start booting in one mode, you cannot switch. Or grub can only boot other installs in same boot mode.If UEFI system, use gpt partitioning & UEFI install, if Windows is UEFI.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the options of the [grub configuration file](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Configuration) with the actual `grub.cfg` build by `grub-mkconfig`.

To edit the options, you have to edit the file `/etc/default/grub`, and then run `sudo update-grub`:

```
# /etc/default/grub
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="menu"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX="keep"
```

then

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: No, unfortunately your suggestion doesn't work. I just get a grub.cfg without menu and countdown options and at the boot no countdown is shown and it doesn't start the firs OS of the menu